# beginner troubles with if statement

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the `if` statement in C# to check if my name is written in the name string

```
string navn = " ";
Console.WriteLine("skriv dit navn her: ");
navn = Console.ReadLine();
if (navn = "jannik");
```

But it won't do what I tell it to. If anyone would be so kind as to enlighten me about what I am doing wrong here I would be very glad :)

Comment: This time it's pretty obvious, but next time when you get an error message (which you should, if you try to compile this), be sure to post it in your question.

Answer (score 5):

Use `==` to compare values. `=` is only for setting values.

Also, putting a semicolon (`;`) immediately after an `if` statement makes the `if` statement do nothing. You sure you didn't mean to put something else in there?

Comment: i wanted to put i console.writeline ("hello master"); in there but i just didn't get to it yet :)

Answer (score 4):

```
if (navn = "jannik");
```

**You have a semicolon at the end of your if statement**. That `(;)` is a valid statement and if statement will just act on that. You need to do:

```
if (navn == "jannik")
{
 Console.Write("MyName");
}
```

Also for comparing equality, you need `==` not a single `=`

You can also look at [String.Equals Method (String, String, StringComparison)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx) for comparison with ignore case.

```
if (navn.Equals("jannik", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    //My Name
}
else
{
    //Some other name
}
```